# Tomcat - 404 error with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have installed apache Tomcat an I have a problem. When I start the server using "Monitor Tomcat" I have acces to `localhost:8080/` but when I add the server to Eclipse end then run it I have 404 error. I also get this error when i try to run any project on server.

I have tried to reinstall Tomcat but it does not help. Any idea how can I fix it?

My Tomcat version is 8.0.24. I have also tried with version 7 but i did not worked

**EDIT:**

@Gimby

Step by step what I did:

1. install Tomcat 8
2. Run Eclipse
3. Add new server Tomcat 8 at "localhost". Then I chose Tomcat location and chose JREs as: jdk1.8.0_45 (default) and clicked finish. This added server to Eclipse.
4. I've created new Dynamic Web Project and added a servlet to it. I also overwritten doGet() method to print text.
5. Run as -> run on server -> Tomcat 8 -> 404 error

Server logs in consloe are fine. There are no errors.

Comment: I'm missing the step of you actually deploying a web application, currently you may just have a running server without a root webapp running so its no wonder you get a 404. In any case, you'll have to provide actual steps you took to setup everything before anyone can have any idea about what might be wrong.

Comment: well by default if you hit the localhost:8080 you will get the ROOT application that Tomcat has in with it's admin page. Also when you start it in eclipse , are you seeing the server logs ? it starts properly ? also could you check the in eclipse server's settings ,the default HTTP port isn't changed

Comment: I've added edit to my previous post answering your questions

Comment: Try to modify you host context on your tomcat server.xml to reach your app with localhost:8080 or try to reach localhost:8080/YouAppName

Comment: I can't reach localhost:8080/MyAppName. It gives me 404 error. And what do you mean by "modify you host context on your tomcat server.xml"? Can you explain that more specific. I am just starting to work with Tomcat...